# builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function, conv-neural-network

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = lr)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
valid_loss_min = np.Inf



    def train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
        model.train()
        for batch_idx, (img_data32,img_data64, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
            img_data32,img_data64, target = Variable(img_data32.to(device)),Variable(img_data64.to(device)), Variable(target.to(device))
            optimizer.zero_grad()  # Gradient Zeroing
            output = model(img_data32,img_data64)
            loss = criterion(output,target.view(1, -1).float)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()  # Update gradient
            if(batch_idx+1)%150 == 0:
                print("saving model ...")
                torch.save(model.state_dict(),'{}/gdrive/My Drive/RA/HEVC-CU/model_MSEloss_Adam_0.001.pt'.format(LOAD_DIR))
            if(batch_idx+1)%100 == 0:
                print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                    epoch, batch_idx * len(img_data32), len(train_loader.dataset),
                    100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))



    def validation(model, device, validation_loader,epoch):
        global valid_loss_min,startTick
        model.eval()
        print("start validation...")
        validation_loss = 0
        correct = 0
        label = []
        for i in range(16):
            label.append(str(i))
        with torch.no_grad():
            for img_data32,img_data64, target in validation_loader:
                img_data32,img_data64, target = img_data32.to(device),img_data64.to(device), target.to(device)
                output = model(img_data32,img_data64)
                validation_loss = criterion(output,target.view(1,-1).float)

                for i,single_pred in enumerate(output):
                    pred_0 = torch.argmax(single_pred[0:4])
                    pred_1 = torch.argmax(single_pred[4:8])
                    pred_2 = torch.argmax(single_pred[8:12])
                    pred_3 = torch.argmax(single_pred[12:16])
                    pred = str(int(pred_0)) + str(int(pred_1)) + str(int(pred_2)) + str(int(pred_3))
                    target_0 = int(target[i,0])
                    target_1 = int(target[i,1])
                    target_2 = int(target[i,2])
                    target_3 = int(target[i,3])
                    if str(pred[0]) == str(target_0):
                        correct += 1
                    if str(pred[1]) == str(target_1):
                        correct += 1
                    if str(pred[2]) == str(target_2):
                        correct += 1
                    if str(pred[3]) == str(target_3):
                        correct += 1
        validation_loss = validation_loss*BATCH_SIZE/len(validation_loader.dataset)
        timeSpan = time.clock() - startTick  # Calculation takes time
        print('EPOCH:{}    Time used:{}    Validation set: Average loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch,str(timeSpan),validation_loss))
        print('\nAccuracy: {}/{} ({:.2f}%)\n'.format(correct, len(validation_loader.dataset)*4, 100. * correct / len(validation_loader.dataset)/4))
        if validation_loss < valid_loss_min:
            valid_loss_min = validation_loss
            print("saving model ...")
            torch.save(model.state_dict(),'{}/gdrive/My Drive/RA/HEVC-CU/model_MSEloss_Adam_0.001.pt'.format(LOAD_DIR))


    for epoch in range(1, EPOCHS + 1):
        train(model, DEVICE, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
        validation(model, DEVICE, validation_loader,epoch)




/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:443: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([1, 16])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([4, 16])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-c7589b926dae> in <module>()
      1 for epoch in range(1, EPOCHS + 1):
----> 2     train(model, DEVICE, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
      3     validation(model, DEVICE, validation_loader,epoch)

3 frames
<ipython-input-144-a7cdc82e4f14> in train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
     17         #loss = criterion(output[:,0:4], target[:,0].float)+criterion(output[:,4:8], target[:,1].float)+criterion(output[:,8:12], target[:,2].float)+criterion(output[:,12:16], target[:,3].float)
     18         #loss = criterion(output,target.view(1,-1))
---> 19         loss = criterion(output,target.view(1, -1))
     20         loss.backward()
     21         optimizer.step()  # Update gradient

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    491             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    492         else:
--> 493             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    494         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    495             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    441     @weak_script_method
    442     def forward(self, input, target):
--> 443         return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
    444 
    445 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in mse_loss(input, target, size_average, reduce, reduction)
   2255     else:
   2256         expanded_input, expanded_target = torch.broadcast_tensors(input, target)
-> 2257         ret = torch._C._nn.mse_loss(expanded_input, expanded_target, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction))
   2258     return ret
   2259 

RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Long for argument #2 'target'
```

I was using cross-entropy loss function before but now I gonna to use MSE but I got this error:

**"AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'size'"**

I tried these as well:

```
loss = criterion(output,target.view(1,-1))
validation_loss = criterion(output,target.view(1,-1))
```

but it get me this error:

**RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Long for argument #2 'target'**

I will appreciate if anyone helps me to solve this.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: I added traceback part to my post!

Comment: Try adding changing target.view(1,-1) to target.view(1,-1).float()

Comment: Great. It works, Thank you so much!!!